# Loading a private image from Supabase in Flutterflow

Tags: supabase, flutterflow

Flutterflow has a handy native feature for uploading images to Supabase storage, but it's not clear how the uploaded image can then be accessed *if*, as in my case, Supabase has a security policy on the bucket.

The policy is by design - I only want user-uploaded images to be available to the user that uploaded them, but I can't see an obvious way to make authenticated requests to Supabase to get the image, i.e. the GET needs the bearer token. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a private bucket and want to retrieve images from the bucket as a signed in user, you have to first [create a signed URL](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/storage-from-createsignedurl) and then load the image using the generated signed URL.

```dart
final String signedUrl = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .createSignedUrl('avatar1.png', 60);
```